# Does the wiring of a coil change magnetic field direction?

Tags: electromagnetism

If a coil is wired clockwise or counter-clockwise, does it change the magnetic field direction of the coil?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an extremely thin wire and a long solenoid, the answer is no.  Either way, the magnetic field inside the solenoid only depends on the direction of current flow in the wire.  One can determine the direction of the magnetic field using the right hand rule. The vanishingly small net current along the axis of the solenoid (which is determined why the direction of wrapping) is insufficient to produce a significant excess magnetic field perpendicular to the axis of the solenoid.

Comment: what about in a short coil with extremely thick wire, like an induction heater? https://i.ibb.co/5kkcwnL/levitationcoil1.jpg

Comment: That shape looks really messy. It doesn't have a lot of symmetry so I imagine the magnetic field inside and outside is quite sensitive to the shape of the wound coil including it's direction of winding.